# Query que só retorna o resulta caso um campo esteja noutra tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

O titulo é capaz não representar bem a questão.

Tenho uma tabela com informações sobre carros(id(CP), nome, modelo, entre outros) e outra com os "Extras"(id(CP), id_carro(CS), nome_do_extra) que os carros têm.

```
    +---------------------+
    |      tbl_carros     |
    +---------------------+
    | ID | Marca | Modelo |
    +----+-------+--------+
    | 22 | VW    | Golf   |
    +----+-------+--------+
    | 23 | Smart | ForTwo |
    +----+-------+--------+
    | 34 | BMW   | 740d   |
    +----+-------+--------+

+------------------------------+
|          tbl_extras          |
+------------------------------+
| ID | id_car | Extra          |
+----+--------+----------------+
| 1  | 22     | Airbag         |
+----+--------+----------------+
| 2  | 22     | ABS            |
+----+--------+----------------+
| 3  | 22     | Cruise Control |
+----+--------+----------------+
| 4  | 24     | ABS            |
+----+--------+----------------+
| 5  | 24     | Airbag         |
+----+--------+----------------+
```

Acima estão as tais duas tabelas em questão.

O que eu precisava era de uma forma de apresentar os dados do carro(Marca, Modelos) **SÓ** se os extras que quero estão relacionados com ele, isto é, quando eu pedir todos os carros com ABS e Cruise Control, o único resultado, neste caso, seja VW Golf, numa só row. Se existir mais que um carro com os mesmo extras, também precisava que fosse apresentado.

Espero bem que fiz-me entender. Sempre posso responder a mais alguma dúvida que tenham.

**O que já tentei**

Já tentei fazer uma query em que uma das condições era o registo estar presente noutra tabela, mas como os extras estão separados por rows, não conseguia procurar por todas as linhas e ao mesmo tempo, apresentar só um registo.

Ou seja, as soluções que tentei explorar não me parecem eficientes ou são em demasia complicadas e por simples falta de conhecimentos(experiência), não estou a ver como posso fazer isso.

Comment: Pesquise por subqueries com EXISTS

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Ok, já tenho experimentado com o exists, parece que estou a bom caminho mas mesmo assim ainda não estou a ver o que corre mal, tenho aqui a query que estou a utilizar agora. SELECT *
FROM   Veiculos
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   Extras 
                   WHERE  Extras.id_car = Veiculos.ID AND Extras.Extra = 'ABS' AND Extras.Extra = 'Cruise Control')

Comment: Quando tenho só um extras 'ABS' tenho o resultado desejado. Mas basta ter um parametro a mais que já devolve "0 resultado". Penso que o que a query faz é procurar o 'ABS' e 'Cruise Control' num só campo e não em todos.

Comment: RESPOSTA: Ok, com o concelho do @Motta consegui resolver o problema. SELECT Veiculos.ID
FROM   Veiculos
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   Extras 
                   WHERE  Extras.id_car = Veiculos.ID AND Extras.Extra = 'Fecho centralizado')
       AND 
       EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   Extras 
                   WHERE  Extras.id_car = Veiculos.ID AND Extras.Extra = 'Livro de revisões completo')

Comment: Recomendo a leitura nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Comment: @PashaZakharuk: E se a pesquisa for por 3 acessórios?   ;) //  Sugestão: monte código que funcione independente do número de itens a pesquisar.

Comment: @JoséDiz A query é suposta ser 'construída' dinamicamente. No meu caso estou a construir um menu de pesquisa avançada, como tem em sites de compras, "preço", "marca", "ano" **"extras que tem"**. Assim uma vez que os parâmetros estejam escolhidos, construo a query. Acha errado essa prática? EDIT: Respondendo a sua pergunta "e se a pesquisa for por _n_ acessórios", da forma como tenho desenvolvido, vou conseguir juntar varias condições antes de executar a query.

Comment: @PashaZakharuk: Além de poder selecionar vários extras, o usuário pode também selecionar, por exemplo, várias marcas/modelos em uma mesma pesquisa?

Comment: @JoséDiz Sim. Mas com essa parte não tenho tido problemas. O que eu quero dizer por 'construir dinamicamente' é, por exemplo: `SELECT * FROM Veiculos WHERE Marca = 'Smart'` e caso o utilizador indicar o modelo irei, com o PHP, acrescentar uma condição `"AND Modelo='ForFour'"` e com a query formada fazer o pedido a BD

Comment: @PashaZakharuk: Uma abordagem é montar o código da consulta no aplicativo, em tempo de execução. Esse código sempre será _compilado_ pelo SQL Server, antes de ser executado. Outra abordagem é criar previamente procedimento armazenado  com código SQL estático, que receba parâmetros de pesquisa.  //
No caso de código da consulta montado em tempo de execução, você deve avaliar qual forma é mais eficiente: se vários AND NOT EXISTS em sequência ou se a forma proposta por Sorack/José Diz, que são semelhantes.

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Eis a sugestão para o que solicita, que funciona com qualquer número de acessórios a pesquisar.

```
-- código #1
-- informe os extras a pesquisar
CREATE TABLE #Pesquisa (Extra varchar(30) unique);
INSERT into #Pesquisa values
  ('ABS'),
  ('Cruise Control');

-- calcula número de itens extras a pesquisar
declare @Qtd int;
set @Qtd= (SELECT count(*) from #Pesquisa);

-- monta lista de extras em uma variável
declare @Acessórios varchar(200);
set @Acessórios= '';
SELECT @Acessórios+= (Extra + ', ') from #Pesquisa;
set @Acessórios= left(@Acessórios, (len(@Acessórios) -1));

--
with ctePesqExtra as (
SELECT id_car
  from tbl_extras as T1
       inner join #Pesquisa as T2 on T1.Extra = T2.Extra
  group by id_car
  having count(*) = @Qtd
)
SELECT C.*, @Acessórios as [Acessórios]
  from tbl_carros as C
       inner join ctePesqExtra as E on C.ID = E.id_car;
```

---

Código para gerar a massa de dados para testes:

```
-- código #2
set nocount on;

CREATE TABLE tbl_carros (
  ID int not null primary key,
  Marca varchar(20) not null,
  Modelo varchar(30) not null
);
INSERT into tbl_carros values
   (22, 'VW', 'Golf'),
   (23, 'Smart', 'ForTwo'),
   (24, 'BMW', '740d');

CREATE TABLE tbl_extras (
  id int identity,
  id_car int references tbl_carros(ID),
  Extra varchar(30)
);
CREATE clustered INDEX I1_tbl_extras on tbl_extras (id_car);

INSERT into tbl_extras (id_car, Extra) values
   (22, 'Airbag'),
   (22, 'ABS'),   
   (22, 'Cruise Control'),
   (24, 'ABS'),
   (24, 'Airbag');
go
```

---

Posto isto, sugiro que crie uma terceira tabela contendo a lista de acessórios, independente de marca/modelo de veículo. Dessa forma, na tabela tbl_extras ficariam somente o código do veículo e o código do acessório. É mais confiável pesquisar por código do que por texto.

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue realizar a consulta utilizando a cláusula `HAVING` juntamente com um `JOIN` na tabela `tbl_extras`:

```
SELECT tc.id
  FROM tbl_carros tc
       INNER JOIN tbl_extras te ON te.id_car = tc.id_car
 WHERE te.extra IN ('ABS', 'Cruise Control')
 GROUP BY tc.id
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2
```

Explicando a `query` acima:

- Utilizo o `INNER JOIN` para buscar os extras de cada veículo;
- Na cláusula `IN` restrinjo apenas pelos extras que desejo que estejam presentes no veículo em questão;
- O `GROUP BY` indica que o resultado será contado para cada `id` de veículo, independentemente dos outros campos;
- A cláusula `HAVING` é utilizada quando queremos restringir os resultados com alguma função de agregação, nesse caso o `COUNT`;
- Conto os registros selecionados e retorno apenas os que tem mais de 2, garantindo que serão retornados apenas veículos que possuem pelo menos 2 registros na `tbl_extras` com as descrições filtradas.